# updateMany with different values MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a collection in MongoDB called "Users". Here, I want to update two specefic documents with different values on request. So far, I have succeded with selecting them both, but I can't seem to find a way to specefy the values. I can only give them the same value. Here is what I have so far:

```
db.db(DBName).collection("Users").updateMany(

{id: {$in: [1, 2]}}, 

{$set: {Value: "test"}}
```

This works fine but both of them of cause gains the value "test". Is there a way to specefy what the id: 1 gains the value "test1" and the id: 2 gains the value "test2"?

Answer (score 0):

Update many is similar to a SQL query that matches multiple documents in an `UPDATE` statement. It's meant to update many documents with the same new data. If you would like to set different records to different values, simply issue `.update()` twice (or more) with your different conditions and different update values.

Comment: But can I do that on the same path? E.g. if the execution is done when the user clicks a button?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to do that?